# The name does not exist in the current context (razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a few issues with razor and yet again it's stressing me out.

I opened a project which is littered with *Red Squiggles* within the razor. This is very much a challenge as I'm a Webforms developer moving over to MVC.

I'm running visual studio 2015 enterprise.

At first I thought it might be a version issue but all seems good. WebConfig seems up to date. I'm at a loss, and in need of guidance. Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

**///EDITS**

Views web.config.

```
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

It looks like I'm missing the razor namespace. I cannot actually add this in the references.

Comment: So there is also a web.config in the views folder.  Can you post it as well?

Comment: Hi @ErikPhilips thanks for the speedy reply. Yes, web.config exists. Seems in order.

Comment: Clean your solution, Rebuild,Restart VS. Did you try any of those ?

Comment: @Shyju yes, that was my first plan of attack.(all)

Comment: What is the version of dll specified in following line `<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, **Version=5.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`. Make sure it is 5.0.0.0 or greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate section `<system.web.webPages.razor>` in you web.config. This configuration file can be found under Views -> web.config. 
If you have **version 4.0.0.0** for `System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory` then change it to **Version=5.0.0.0**. It should look like below:

`<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

**Note:** Make sure you call all the views in Visual studio and re-open them.

Comment: Hi, Just tried the above still didn't work. Thanks for your time. Getting rather frustrated now.

Comment: Can you create a sample project where it can be reproduced? Put it on github or bitbucket. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like your UI project is missing the MVC and Razor assembly references.

Check the references for

`System.Web.MVC`

`System.Web.Razor`

`System.Web.Webpages`

`System.Web.Webpages.Razor`

Comment: Re-edits above. I'm missing razor. Iv'e tried to "add reference" but I'm struggling to find "System.Web.Razor". I may be missing something simple here haha

Comment: You should use Nuget package manager in IDE to get the required assembly files.

Comment: All of the above exist...I'm very familiar with nuget, I think MVC is throwing me. I'm starting to think it's a VS15 issue.