# The name 'model' does not exist in current context in ASP.NET Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to develop a website with plugins using ASP.NET Core. I have my main project, asp.net web application which works fine. I have a class library project with controllers which also works fine and views which I have a problem with. When I open *.cshtml file I can see that Razor doesn't work - @using, @model and other directives are not recognized and intellisense doesn't work. When I hover over model I'm given the error from title:

> The name 'model' does not exist in current context in ASP.NET Core

I use EmbeddedFileProvider for discovering views and they're marked as Embedded resource. When I run application everything works - views are rendered correctly. My only issue is false-positive errors in Visual Studio. I googled and there similar issues, but mainly for ASP.NET MVC, not Core - [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context). I think something is missing in class library configuration, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: Follow this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764916/6557649 Works for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new csproj file has an "Sdk" attribute at the top level "Project" element. When you create a new Web application, this gets set to the "Web" SDK:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">...</Project>
```

When you add/create a class library, it defaults to the standard non-web SDK:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">...</Project>
```

As far as I can tell, the Web SDK imports additional tasks to allow design-time processing of Web resources, such as Razor views. **Change the SDK** in your **plugin library** to Web.

Another parameter of a "Web" project is that it outputs an EXE by default, so also add this to your plugin csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i was missing when upgrading from old project.json to new VS17 type. My project was Microsoft.Net.Sdk instead of sdk.web

Comment: I have same problem, in MVC web site project, which has the sdk directive as you said, however, Model, the model type is not recgonized and underlined as mistakes in all views