# Model in view showing new Red after changing target to 2.0 then back to 3.21

Tags: asp.net-core, model

I have wrote a ASP.NEt Core 3.21 web app and found out GoDaddy only supports 2.0. I changed the target to this and found it's no long supported so I changed it back but now any reference to the Model in my views is erroring: -

The name Model does not exist in the current context.

Any help please,

Comment: Sorry it was 3.1

Comment: Have you refactored the project, will he report an error? Or you can refer to this article, which may be helpful to you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499009/the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-current-context-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by refactored the project. When I changed the default target framework to 2.0 and then back I get errors referencing any to do with the @ symbol.

Comment: I;ve even added a new project and get the same result. Any help please...